# php parsing json data

Tags: php, json

Never had to do this one and getting confused about the format and how to access specific variables out of it.

The result of :

```
$result = json_decode($result);
print_r($result);
```

is :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [input] => stdClass Object
        (
            [address_components] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [number] => 1109
                    [predirectional] => N
                    [street] => Highland
                    [suffix] => St
                    [formatted_street] => N Highland St
                    [city] => Arlington
                    [state] => VA
                    [zip] => 22201
                    [country] => US
                )

            [formatted_address] => 1109 N Highland St, Arlington, VA 22201
        )

    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [address_components] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [number] => 1109
                            [predirectional] => N
                            [street] => Highland
                            [suffix] => St
                            [formatted_street] => N Highland St
                            [city] => Arlington
                            [county] => Arlington County
                            [state] => VA
                            [zip] => 22201
                            [country] => US
                        )

                    [formatted_address] => 1109 N Highland St, Arlington, VA 22201
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [lat] => 38.886672
                            [lng] => -77.094735
                        )

                    [accuracy] => 1
                    [accuracy_type] => rooftop
                    [source] => Arlington
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [address_components] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [number] => 1109
                            [predirectional] => N
                            [street] => Highland
                            [suffix] => St
                            [formatted_street] => N Highland St
                            [city] => Arlington
                            [county] => Arlington County
                            [state] => VA
                            [zip] => 22201
                            [country] => US
                        )

                    [formatted_address] => 1109 N Highland St, Arlington, VA 22201
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [lat] => 38.886665
                            [lng] => -77.094733
                        )

                    [accuracy] => 1
                    [accuracy_type] => rooftop
                    [source] => Virginia Geographic Information Network (VGIN)
                )

        )

)
```

How can I access the lat and lng values?  I am getting confused since there are objects and arrays mixed within.  I've never worked with json in this manner with php... it is a geocoding api that returns in json format.

I basically want to do something like `$lat = $result['results'][0]['location']['lat'];` and so on.

Comment: Use type casting, convert it into object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `true` as second parameter in `json_decode` so that output will be normal php array not `stdclass` array(so that you can use your approach what you are trying)

So do like below:-

```
$result = json_decode($result,true);

echo $lat = $result['results'][0]['location']['lat'];
echo $lng = $result['results'][0]['location']['lng'];
```

***Note:-***

***1.*** With your current format also you can get data like below:-

```
echo $lat = $result->results[0]->location->lat; //using object approach 
echo $lng = $result->results[0]->location->lng; //using object approach
```

***2.*** Use `foreach()` to get all `lat-lng` records.

```
foreach($result->results as $val) { //if using stdclass array
   echo "Latitude = ".$val->location->lat;
   echo "Longitude = ".$val->location->lng;
}
```

Or:-

```
foreach($result['results'] as $val) {//if using normal array
   echo "Latitude = ".$val['location']['lat'];
   echo "Longitude = ".$val['location']['lng'];
}
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something simple I was missing... that is what I was looking for... thanks!

Comment: @user756659  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

You can access lat lng from result as below

```
$result = json_decode($result);
echo $result->results[0]->location->lat;
echo $result->results[0]->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use second parameter as true for convert all object to array. Otherwise you can get values like this.

```
$result->results[0]->location->lat;
$result->results[0]->location->lng;
```

Comment: it's `lng` not `long`. Now +1 because you are correct too.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that from your example you have multiple records to fetch. Use a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to print the details

```
$result = json_decode($result);
foreach($result->results as $value) {
   echo "Lat--",$value->location->lat; //using object
   echo "Long--",$value->location->lng;
}
```